# How can i compare a string content each n seconds adter a new content have been downloaded?

Tags: c#

I have this code :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {

                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {



                    string content = downloadContent();
                    if (InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = content), null);
                    }

                    GetProfileNames(content);
                    GetTextFromProfile(content);


                    reader.Close();
                    response.Close();
                    Thread.Sleep(30000);
                }
            }
        }
```

And the downloadContent function:

```
private string downloadContent()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(testingUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";
            response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return content;
        }
```

I need that every 30 seconds it will download a new content like it does now, store the old content one before and compare the new download with the one before downloaded content.

If they are identical dont do anything if they are not identical do something.

Comment: And what's wrong with the code right now? Any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a variable to store the last content. This variable should be placed outside the BGWorker DoWork method.

```
string LastContent = "";
```

Then, under this line:

```
string content = downloadContent();
```

Add these to see if they are same or not:

```
if (content == LastContent)
{
   e.Cancel=true;
   LastContent=content;
   break;
}
else
{
   //Do something if they are not equal.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the timer classes in .NET.

[`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) is a good choice if you are not on winforms, though you need to understand that it will run on its own thread.

```
var timer = new Timer(30000); // Interval of 30 seconds
timer.Elapsed = OnTimedEvent;
timer.Start();

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Update logic here.
}
```